# CASE statement based on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query that results in the output below (this output is for only 1 `servicelocation_id`, but there are thousands). I need to create a `CASE` statement that will look at the multiple rows for a 'Utility' to determine the output.

If there is a NULL 'todate' in any row for a specific 'Utility' (Solid Waste for example) I want to create a 'Status' column with a value of 'Active'. If all rows for a specific 'Utility' do have a 'todate', I want the value to be 'Inactive.'

I can't do a MAX on the 'fromdate' to determine if the utility is active or not because it is possible a row with a 'todate' has a more recent 'fromdate' than a row that doesn't have one.

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I had to cobble together a view and the write a query on top of that. It's a bit of a mess so I thought providing the output might make it easier.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Stedman . . . What results do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `servicelocation_id`/`utility` you want an aggregation:

```
select servicelocation_id, utility,
       (case when count(*) = count(to_date)
             then 'Inactive' else 'Active'
        end) as flag
from t
group by servicelocation_id, utility;
```

If you want to keep your original rows, this can easily be adapted to use window functions instead of aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `CASE WHEN EXISTS()` with a correlated sub-query in the `EXISTS()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your case statement in a sub-query A, then use a subquery B to select from A, using a Group By that takes the min of status.  That way, if there is an "Active", that will be the value, otherwise "Inactive" will be the value.

*Edited to include utility in the grouping/join per requirements*

```
    SELECT YT.servicelocation_id, YT.fromdate, YT.todate, YT.Utility, B.Status
    FROM YourTable YT
    LEFT JOIN 
    (--B subquery
        SELECT servicelocation_id, utility, min(Status) as Status
        FROM (--A subquery
                SELECT servicelocation_id, utility, CASE WHEN todate IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as Status
             ) A
        GROUP BY servicelocation_id, utility
    ) B ON YT.servicelocation_id = B.servicelocation_id and YT.utility = B.utility
    --Optional WHERE clause
    WHERE YT.YourField = 'YourCriteria'
```

Based on the input given for servicelocation_id 84061, they would all have status of "Active" since each utility has at least one value where todate is NULL.